# Trying to get a local MSSQL server for SQLTools plugin for vscode working under linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sql-server, visual-studio-code, ms-sql

I enrolled in a DBMS course in college, the professor has been explicitly using MySQL.

The labs have Ubuntu and Windows on dual boot, but the Windows installation is old and really slow.

I have been trying to get vs-code plugin [SQLTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools) along with this guide for setting up the MSSQL Server using [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017).

I can connect to the server using this command via the terminal:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA
```

The issue arises: When I try to connect using `localhost`, `username:SA` and port 1433, through SQLTools plugin or the official MSSQL plugin for vscode though connection never succeeds.

It'd be lovely if I could get a similar setup working on my own PC running Windows 10 and Elementary OS. Since I could virtually recreate all of my database, since all my syntax is going to be inside one SQL file that I am going to submit for assignments.

Comment: I don't believe I got it right. You are able to login to MSSQL using `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA`. But what tool are you using to connect when trying to connect using **localhost , username:SA and port 1433**? Are you trying to login from a remote computer when you get the error? What's the error you get when the connection fails?

Comment: I am using the [SQLTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools) plugin for vscode, to connect to the MSSQL server hosted on the same computer.

Comment: I just installed that tool and tried against a MSSQL server and it worked flawlessly. Try removing the port as it is not needed.

Comment: What does this line mean int the context of your MySQL issues? “I enrolled in a DBMS course in college, the professor has been explicitly using MySQL.”

Comment: I never tagged the question with MySQL, but with sql-server and MS-SQL .

Comment: Also instead of handshake timeout I got an ECONNREFUSED error when not specifying a port where it defualts to 3306.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid connection set I just tested on my desktop:

[image]

By the description in your question you only specified **Server**, **Port** and **Username**. Verify that you have all the other information.

Please note that in my Server configuration I had to add one more information (\sqldeveloper) since I don't have a default SQL Server Instance, but you should be fine with just localhost as it worked for you when using SQLCMD.

There was one time I tried to connect and it just kept loading without success, but I restarted SQLTools and it worked fine.

Comment: doing the same with port 1433 leads to a handshake timeout, without a port value where it defaults to 3306 I receive a ECONNREFUSED error.

Comment: @Blake, can you check [sql server log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log?view=sql-server-2017) to find out if the attempt was logged with more detailed info?